# Swift 3 attributes tag

Tags: class, attributes, swift3

I'm trying to search something about attribute tags like golang struct tags, i did not found nothing about, in swift we have at least an alternative?

Golang Struct:

```
struct {
microsec  uint64 "field 1"
serverIP6 uint64 "field 2"
process   string "field 3"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no such attribute tags readily available in Swift; for details regarding available declaration and type attributes in Swift, refer to:

- [Swift Language Reference - Attributes](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Attributes.html)

If we focus on runtime introspection, however, you can use the [`Mirror` structure](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/mirror) to print the property names of your type, as follows:

```
struct Foo {
    let microsec: UInt64  //"field 1"
    let serverIP6: UInt64 // "field 2"
    let process: String   // "field 3"
    init(_ microsec: UInt64, _ serverIP6: UInt64, _ process: String) {
        self.microsec = microsec
        self.serverIP6 = serverIP6
        self.process = process
    }
}

let foo = Foo(100, 999, "foo")

Mirror(reflecting: foo).children.forEach { print($0.0 ?? "no field name") }
/* microsec
   serverIP6
   process   */
```

If the single purpose of the attribute tags you mention is runtime introspection using `Mirror`, then you may implement your own custom `Mirror` for your type, by conforming to the [`CustomReflectable` protocol](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/customreflectable), fit for your introspection purposes. In this custom implementation, you may replace the default property names with fields of your own. E.g.:

```
struct Foo {
    let microsec: UInt64 //"field 1"
    let serverIP6: UInt64 // "field 2"
    let process: String // "field 3"
    init(_ microsec: UInt64, _ serverIP6: UInt64, _ process: String) {
        self.microsec = microsec
        self.serverIP6 = serverIP6
        self.process = process
    }
}

extension Foo : CustomReflectable {
    var customMirror: Mirror {
        return Mirror(self, children: [
            "field 1" : "\(microsec)",
            "field 2" : "\(serverIP6)",
            "field 3" : process
        ])
    }
}

let foo = Foo(100, 999, "foo")

Mirror(reflecting: foo).children
    .forEach { print($0.0 ?? "no field name", $0.1) }
/* field 1 100
   field 2 999
   field 3 foo */
```

Comment: Thank you for answering, dfri.

Comment: @eduardo happy to help!